# How to highlight all cells that has been sum up

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, highlighting

Imagine I have 4 cells A1, A2, A3, A4

I summed A1 to A3 in cell A4

Is there any formula or conditional formatting that will help highlight Cell A1 to Cell A3 by selecting Cell A4 without clicking on the formula.

Sheet will be locked so the user won't have access to formula

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Formulas cannot change appearance of cells, and Conditional Formatting cannot be based on active/selected cell. So the answer is no. The only possible way to do something like this would be with VBA Macros, something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358227/5518385

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This will happen automatically if you click on A4 and then click inside
the formula :

[image]

Comment: I mean the first one, when u click on A4 only, i want it to hightlight without clicking on the formula, infact the sheet will be protected, and no one will be able to click on the formula

Comment: In this case there is no way for this to be done, unless you're willing to write a VBA click-handler that will select the cells, which won't be an easy task.

Comment: Yeah i thought so, anyway, thank you so much for clearing my thoughts 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of conditional fortmatting, you could format the data as table without headers and add a totals row.

You could then color the totals row field to your liking and if you add more items to the column, the formatted totals row will shift down automatically. The same applies to coloring the actual data colums.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by combining `SelectionChange event` with `Conditional Formatting`.

In the sheet module place the event procedure:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.HasFormula Then
      Me.Unprotect
      Names.Add "Args", "=" & Target.DirectPrecedents.Address
      Me.Protect
   Else
      On Error Resume Next
      Names("Args").Delete
      On Error GoTo 0
   End If
End Sub
```

When a cell with formula has been selected the name "Args" is created. It contains addresses of cells which are used within the formula. When selected cell does not contain a formula the name "Args" is deleted.

Next step is to define another name in the Name manager which is necessary to define the rule for Conditional Formatting. This name is called "test" and refers to:
`=ISREF(Sheet1!A1 Sheet1!Args)`

`Sheet1` is the sheet name (when you are defining this name you can omit it, will be added by Excel).
`A1` is the relative address of an active cell. There is a space (means intersection) between the two addresses.

Definition of conditional formatting formula is simply:
`=test`
The scope you define according to your needs.

How does it work? When you select a cell with a formula, all cells on which the formula depends on are highlighted as defined in conditional formatting. When you change the selection to a cell without formula, highlighting disappears.

[Sample file is here](https://polslpl-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mgonet_polsl_pl/ERrWGvkqlu5Op_dlsOx42u8B4uLFLdxrwOh6FmzF5bG4Kw?e=euaJm4)

[image]